# Is passing username and password via secure URL (SSL) safe from a man in the middle attack?

Tags: ssl, password-protection

I have a few RSS feeds that I subscribed to. My problem is that my feed reader does not prompt for user name or password, so in order to get my feed data I have to use https://{username}:{password}@domain.com/rss/feed rather than just https://domain.com/rss/feed.

Is my username and password safe?

Comment: When you type an address like `https://{username}:{password}@domain.com/rss/feed`, the username and passwords are passed via HTTP authentication headers, which are protected by HTTPS like any other HTTP header (provided the usual verifications are made properly).

Answer (score 0):

Does your RSS feed client verify the server certificate? If the client verifies the particular certificate, then you are safe. If the client just verifies that the certificate has a legitimate signing chain, then you are sort of safe. If the answer is no, then you are not safe.